# C# event firing null from backgroundWorker

Tags: c#, events, null, backgroundworker

I have a library which fires events through this code:

```
  public delegate void ChangedEventHandler(String currentFunction, String PCDMessage, ePcdEventType pcdEventType, ePcdEvent pcdEvent);
  public event ChangedEventHandler OnStatusChange;
```

and

```
protected virtual void RaiseEvent(String strCurrentFunction, String strMessage, ePcdEventType pcdEventType, ePcdEvent pcdEvent)
    {
        if (OnStatusChange != null)
            OnStatusChange(strCurrentFunction, strMessage, pcdEventType, pcdEvent);
    }
```

everything works fine but when I fire the event from the following backgroundWorker

```
 bwExecute = new BackgroundWorker();
 bwExecute.DoWork += BwExecute_DoWork;
 bwExecute.RunWorkerCompleted += Bg_RunWorkerCompleted;
 object[] parameters = new object[] { currentFunc, partProgramFilename, varsValuesList};
 bwExecute.RunWorkerAsync(parameters);
```

the OnStatusChange in the RaiseEvent is always null and therefore never gets fired.
The BwExecute_DoWork is:

```
 private void BwExecute_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        object[] parameters = e.Argument as object[];
        String currentFunc = parameters[0].ToString();
        String partProgramFilename = parameters[1].ToString();
        List<String> varsValueList = (List<String>)parameters[2];

        ExecuteJob(currentFunc,partProgramFilename, varsValueList);
    }
```

and the RaiseEvent are fired in the ExecuteJob routine just as they are fired in the other part of the code.

** ADD ** I noticed that ONLY when called inside the backgroundWorker the OnStatusChange when called inside the RaiseEvent is ALWAYS NULL and so the event is not fired. I always call the RaiseEvent(...) in the same way both outside and inside the background worker. 
Now understood the problem, what is the solution?

** EDIT ** I'm using C# WPF but I don't think this makes any difference...

Thank for any help
Patrick

Comment: Those are all member functions. Are you certain that you are using the correct objects? You might track their creation and make sure that you register your event handler in the same class object that you are using later on. BTW, you never give the code for calling into RaiseEvent. Porobably it is an instantiation issue, though.

Comment: i think its a threading issue, there is a main thread and a background worker thread....and there is data passing issue....why not use dispatcher ? try using this control.dispatcher.Invoke(()=>{//call your function});

Comment: A question though is when you instantiate OnStatusChange. As you define the variable as such but do not set it to anything in the code you show and thus it would be null. So it would be important to know when and where it is instantiated.

Comment: @SaadAbdullah you are right! As I said in my ** ADD ** about it's a threading issue since I am calling the RaiseEvent(...) in the same way both inside and outside the backgroundWorker. Outside it works inside it doesn't. So you are suggesting to use a dispatcher but you are referring to a control. No controls here just an event which is null when inside a backgroundWorker. So how can I correct it? Thanx

Comment: @patrick how do you access OnStatusChange? I mean are you sure you are going for the correct same instance of the class that it is part of in both the foreground and the background worker? (not 100% sure if that is the case from the code you show)

Comment: @thomas this is my code:       **public delegate void ChangedEventHandler(String currentFunction, String PCDMessage, ePcdEventType pcdEventType, ePcdEvent pcdEvent);
        public event ChangedEventHandler OnStatusChange;** while you can see the code above for the RaiseEvent. Yes I'm 100% sure it's the same code in both cases inside and outside the backgroundworker and obviously to match the delegate above it's RaiseEvent(string1, string2,
enum1, enum2).

Comment: ChangedEventhandler is a delegate and thus not the executed code. Normally when you then define the event you need to set it onto some existing function, .... so that it is != null that is what I meant.    Additionally for teh second part I did not mean the code itself it its the same. More if you are sure you are trying to access the same instances. For example if the background worker creates a new OnStatusChanged event variable then its a different one than the other one. Also the question is if when it accesses the variable if it is the same instace it does as the main process does.

Comment: @Thomas: my bad sorry I have misunderstood your comment here is the bw code:  _private void BwExecute_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {_           
            **RaiseEvent("AAAAA", "BBBBB", ePcdEventType.MESSAGE, ePcdEvent.MESS_OPENING_PARTPROGRAM);**
          _ ....
        }_ if I follow the raise event I see that even from here when called, it has a null OnStatusChange event.

Comment: And where do you set OnStatusChange ?  You do declare it as an event but you never set a value to it in any of the code in the question or the code in the comment

Comment: if there isn't any control...then you can create one dyanmically...suppose TextBlock textblock = new TextBlock(); textblock.dispatcher but make sure it is main thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and that is so obvious. Now it's obvious. 
From the main window I called the library functions and only after those I detach the event from the instance of the class.
So if launched without backgroundWorked the execution is serial so first it execute the code and then it detaches the event. 
But when launching the backgroundWorker the execution is parallel so while executing the code it detaches the even before that the aforementioned code is terminated. From this the error. Thanx everyone for helping.